# Android Studio - Ошибка при сборке

Tags: android-studio

При сборке приложения в Android Studio появляется ошибка такого содержания:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

В Интернете пишут, что нужно очистить проект (Build -> Clean). При очистке появляется это:

```
Unable to delete directory: 
D:\MusDown\app\build\intermediates\incremental\ir_slices\debug\package_slice_4
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914499/error-execution-failed-for-task-appclean-unable-to-delete-file/40441712